# Reducing Amount of Categorical Data Categories by Portion of a String

Tags: python, pandas, categorization

I am attempting to sort some categorical data by iterating through a list of strings and am kind of a novice at doing more text based applications in Python. I am attempting to codify some of the categories with a numerical value, as there are some redundancies and too many categories but with similar string notation. I have tried to iterate across the list, and when I do a simple print of each value where the condition is true, the function works just fine, as noted below:

```
TwoKorE="Serial-Two"
lst=data['stuff'].tolist()
x=len(TwoKorE)

twolist=[]

for value in lst:

    if value[0:x]==TwoKorE:

        print(value)
```

However, I would like to append a new categorical variable to the list twolist similar to as below:

```
TwoKorE="Serial-Two"
lst=data['stuff'].tolist()
x=len(TwoKorE)

twolist=[]

for value in lst:

    if value[0:x]==TwoKorE:

        twolist.append(1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any feedback will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is wrong here more specifically?

Comment: More specifically, I get a 'float' object is not subscriptable error in the latter category

Comment: To clarify, there are over 60 categories, some of which are redundant and start with the same words. I'm attempting to just group those into a single category.

Comment: The error literally means the value in the column is of data type float instead of strings. But If your first attempts works, I don't see why you should get an error in the second attempt.

Comment: I agree, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: I'm wondering if there might be a dtype problem.

Comment: According to the error, that should be what is happening. You may want to post a small sample data so that others can help you with.

Comment: I went back and left it in a Series instead of printing out to a list.... I got it to iterate and categorize. It's just now not appending per my wishes. Different battle

Comment: You never had an issue with printing but appending. Same battle. Please post sample data as there are other ways to do this than iterating through all rows.